# Want to create a generic utility method which will convert the type of Dataframe / Dataset based on case class

Tags: scala, dataframe

**Want to create a generic utility method which will responsible to change the type of DataFrame(spark) based on case class design. This scenario will help while pushing the DataFrame to Elasticsearch, since Elasticsearch attribute and type should same with DataFrame column name and type else it will fail to push into ES. and below is the solution.**

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.Serializable
import java.sql.Date
import org.apache.log4j.lf5.LogLevel
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{date_format, _}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{DoubleType, FloatType, IntegerType, StringType}

// Field name should be same as Elasticsearch attribute
case class CaseClass(id: String = "", name: Double = 0.0d, doj: Date = new Date(1999, 0, 0), sal: Double = 0) extends Serializable

object DataTypeConvertion extends SessionFactoryTest with Serializable {

  import spark.implicits._

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val sc = spark.sparkContext
    sc.setLogLevel(LogLevel.WARN.toString)
    val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(
      (101, "1", "2019-08-22T19:26:10.000+0000", "123.45"),
      (102, "2", "2019-08-08T00:00:14.352", "456.78"),
      (103, "3", "2019-08-08T00:01:22.161", "890.12"),
      (101, "1", "2019-08-08T01:12:14.991", "1122.45"),
      (101, "3", "2019-08-08T01:12:21.977", "221.33"),
      (102, "1", "2019-08-08T01:13:09.331", "123.45"),
      (102, "3", "2019-08-08T01:17:10.461", "890.12"),
      (102, "2", "2019-08-08T01:17:15.152", "890.12"),
      (102, "2", "2019-08-08T01:23:09.78", "123.45"),
      (101, "1", "2019-08-08T01:24:10.977", "890.12"),
      (101, "1", "2019-08-08T01:25:17.221", "123.45")
    )).toDF("id", "name", "doj", "sal")

    val res = changeColType(df, CaseClass.apply())
    res.printSchema()
    res.show(false)
  }

  // DF  -> ES based on case class
  def changeColType[T](df: DataFrame, classType: T): DataFrame = {
    val res = df.dtypes.map(cols => (cols._1, classType.getClass.getDeclaredField(cols._1).getType.getName)) :+ ("", "")
    val finalDF = res.foldLeft(res(0), df)((x, y) => {
      val tmpDF = x._1._2 match {
        case "int" => x._2.withColumn(x._1._1, col(x._1._1).cast(IntegerType))
        case "java.lang.String" => x._2.withColumn(x._1._1, col(x._1._1).cast(StringType))
        case "java.sql.Date" => x._2.withColumn(x._1._1, date_format(col(x._1._1), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").as(x._1._1))
        case "float" => x._2.withColumn(x._1._1, col(x._1._1).cast(FloatType))
        case "double" => x._2.withColumn(x._1._1, col(x._1._1).cast(DoubleType))
        case _ => x._2
      }
      (y, tmpDF)
    })
    finalDF._2
  }
}

trait SessionFactoryTest  {
  val spark = SparkSession.builder()
    .appName("SmartBattery ES Push")
    .config("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", true)
    .master("local[*]")
    .getOrCreate()
}
```